# Rewrite the SQL logic in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Can someone help me in re writing this logic in Amazon Redshift? I  tried to re create but getting invalid operator error:

> Operator does not exist: numeric*record

SQL Existing Logic:

```
CASE WHEN Rent * abc.dbo.fnGetinterval('month',DATEADD(DAY,1,Expiration),NextExpiration) > 922337203685477.5807 THEN 
'-999' ELSE 
Rent * abc.dbo.fnGetinterval('month',DATEADD(DAY,1,Expiration),NextExpiration) END
```

the fn get interval stored proc is below:

```
BEGIN
    --Declare local variables
    DECLARE @_Days AS FLOAT
    DECLARE @_IntervalOutput AS FLOAT
    
    --Calculate the date difference in secods
    SELECT @_Days = CONVERT(FLOAT,@EndDate) - CONVERT(FLOAT,@StartDate) 
    
    --Process Seconds Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Second'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = @_Days  *  24  * 60 *  60

    --Process Minutes Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Minute'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = @_Days  *  24  * 60
    
    --Process Hours Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Hour'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = @_Days  *  24

    --Process Days Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Day'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = @_Days

    --Process Weeks Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Week'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = (@_Days /  7)

    --Process Months Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Month'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = (@_Days /  30.436875)

    --Process Quarters Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Quarter'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = (@_Days /  91.310625)

    --Process Years Interval
    IF @Interval = 'Year'
        SELECT @_IntervalOutput = (@_Days /  365.2425)

    --return the calculated interval
    RETURN @_IntervalOutput
END
```

Comment: what is "Rent" datatype and what datatype fnGetinterval returns?

Comment: Hi @eshirvana  the 'RENT' data type is numeric(19,4) and the interval is FLOAT in SQL